# Почему не видит переменную?

Tags: javascript

Ошибка `main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ProgressBar is not defined`?

Запускаю то же самое в codepen и там всё нормально работает

```js
var lineBar = new ProgressBar.Line("#progress-bar__line-container", {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 0.5,
  from: { color: "#FF9900" },
  to: { color: "#00FF99" },
  text: {
    value: '0',
    className: 'progress-text',
    style: {
      color: 'black',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '-30px',
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      transform: null
    }
  },
  step: (state, shape) => {
    shape.path.setAttribute("stroke", state.color);
    shape.setText(Math.round(shape.value() * 100) + ' %');
  }
});

lineBar.animate(1, {
  duration: 4000
});
```

```css
#progress-bar__line-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
    height: 40px;
}

.progress-text {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
          <div id="progress-bar__line-container"></div>
```

Comment: Потому как в CodePen, скорее всего, подключена библиотека, где описан класс `ProgressBar`. У вас в примере кода его нет вовсе, потому и ошибка. Дали бы заодно уж и ссылку на CodePen, где все работает.

Comment: @VenZell точно, спасибо. я не подумал о том, что могла быть подключена сторонняя библиотека!

Answer (score 0):

Изначально в коде была подключена библиотека, поэтому в моём случае код не работал.